# Lost my house in Minecraft. Will it despawn?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What the title says. I'm playing the most recent version on Nintendo Switch as of 6/9/22 on survival mode. I made a house not too far away from my spawn point. I read online that a compass will direct you to your initial spawn point and I tried following it to its pole and it lead me to a biome I had never seen before, certainly not where I spawned.

The world I have is set to infinite and I'm presumably very far away from my house. Will my house despawn if I go too far away from it? Is there anything else I could do to try to find it?

Comment: "it lead me to a biome I had never seen before" any chance you spawned between two different biomes and you started to explore only in one direction? Because the compass will always point your world spawn.

Comment: You sometimes can spawn quite far away from the world spawn, if the world spawn is underwater or not spawnable - it will put you on the nearest-ish (there's some random variation) spawnable place. Is your world spawn an ocean?

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't.

Despawning only applies to mobs and dropped items. Blocks themselves don't despawn, especially not anything built by the player.

If you want, you can read more about despawn on [fandom](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Despawning).

Answer (score 0):

Blocks cannot despawn, no matter how long wait. You can find your house if you continue walking towards the pole. If the pole continously changes direction over one spot, then that's your spawn.

Answer (score 0):

No, blocks do not despawn, even if you walked forever. Walking away from a place only means that only entities like mobs and villagers despawn.